# How to parse out and structure values on newlines as well as on the same line?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

If I have data which is in the following format:

```
[Col1]ABC
[Col2]DEF
[Col3]
GHI
[Col4]
[Col5]

MNO
@
[Col1]CBA
[Col2]FED
[Col3]
IHG
[Col4]
[Col5]
555-12908JLKA
ONM
@
```

I need to extract the values between brackets as well as the values directly after the bracket (which could span multiple lines up to the next opening bracket).

The result expected would be like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
ABC,DEF,GHI,,MNO
CBA,FED,IHG,,555-12908JLKA ONM
```

So the regex to extract [Col1]ABC for example works where the value follows the closing bracket without a space. However, if the information is on a newline it does not work.

`re.findall(r"(\[.*?](.*))", s)`

If I change it to `re.findall(r"(\[.*?]\n(.*))", s)` it does find the ones where there is a newline, but not the ones where the value is not on a newline. Moreover, I also tried to add `re.MULTILINE`, but to no avail.

Because I want to add the result to a dictionary and then convert that dictionary to a dataframe, it needs to have the same number of rows. So it needs to either find a column with a bracket followed directly by the value after the bracket, or it needs to find the column with the value on the newline, but not both. That's also a problem I'm facing.

Comment: What about the `@`? Are they always at the end of the block?

Comment: Pretty much yes

Comment: And all newlines should be replaced with a space?

Comment: or with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'^(?:@\n)?\[([^][]*)](.*(?:\n(?!(?:@\n)?\[[^][]*]).*)*)', s, re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/arNjZM/3).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:@\n)?` - an optional `@` and a newline
- `\[([^][]*)]` - a `[`, then Group 1 matching 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` is matched
- `(.*(?:\n(?!(?:@\n)?\[[^][]*]).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - the rest of the initial line
  - `(?:\n(?!(?:@\n)?\[[^][]*]).*)*` - any 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\n(?!(?:@\n)?\[[^][]*])` - a newline not followed with an optional `@` and a newline followed with a `[`, then 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`
    - `.*` - the rest of the line

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/SgzJxq):

```
import re
s = "[Col1]ABC\n[Col2]DEF\n[Col3]\nGHI\n[Col4]\n[Col5]\n\nMNO\n@\n[Col1]CBA\n[Col2]FED\n[Col3]\nIHG\n[Col4]\n[Col5]\n555-12908JLKA\nONM"
res = re.findall(r'^(?:@\n)?\[([^][]*)](.*(?:\n(?!(?:@\n)?\[[^][]*]).*)*)', s, re.M)
print ([ (x,y.replace("\n", " ")) for x,y in res ])
```

Result:

```
[('Col1', 'ABC'), ('Col2', 'DEF'), ('Col3', ' GHI'), ('Col4', ''), ('Col5', '  MNO'), ('Col1', 'CBA'), ('Col2', 'FED'), ('Col3', ' IHG'), ('Col4', ''), ('Col5', ' 555-12908JLKA ONM')]
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, this is really good and in the right direction. However, this is also taking newlines into account which I of course don't want to use as can be seen from my example output. Also the "@" sign is not in my example output, it's more a delimiter. Is it possible to get rid of those with the regex or do I need to clean it up afterwards?

Comment: @milky You may clean up afterwards since you will still have to match them into blocks of texts.

Comment: All right, fair enough. I will mark as the answer if no one else comes up with anything else. Thanks Wiktor!!

Comment: @milky See the updated answer. Since there is an unknown amount of newlines in the text blocks, they should be replaced in an additional step.

Comment: Thank you for the update! This completes the answer, marked as answer :)